# How to get Country name for related City using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I need help in my project i had a component for cities there is a relation between the cities table and countries table by id how to get the country name for every city in cities component

this is my code in city component

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label class="form-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectAll" @click="select">
                        <i class="form-icon"></i>
                    </label>
                </th>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>City Name</th>
                <th>Country Name</th>
                <th>Created At</th>
                <th>Updated At</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr v-if="cities.length > 0" v-for="(city,index) in cities" :id="city.id">
                <td>
                    <label class="form-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" :value="city.id" v-model="selected">
                        <i class="form-icon"></i>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>{{index+1 }}</td>
                <td>{{city.name}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>{{city.created_at}}</td>
                <td>{{city.updated_at}}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-warning" @click="editModal=true;setVal(city.id,city.name,city.country)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editcity"><i class="fa fa-pen"></i></button></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger" @click="delcity(city.id)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></td>


            </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th><label class="form-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectAll" @click="select">
                    <i class="form-icon"></i>
                </label></th>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>City Name</th>
                <th>Country Name</th>
                <th>Created At</th>
                <th>Updated At</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>

            </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

the second part of code in the city component

```
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            cities:         [],
            countries:      [],
            id:             '',
            name:           '',
            country_id:     '',
            country_name:   '',
            loading:        false,
            showModal:      false,
            editModal:      false,
            selected:       [],
            selectAll:      false,
            csrf:           document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
        }
    },
    methods:{
        getCities(){
            let url = '/dashboard/getCities';
            axios.get(url).then(res=>{
                let link = this;
                this.cities = res.data;
                /*this.cities.forEach(function(item) {
                    link.getCountryName(item.country_id);
                });*/
            })
        },
        getCountryName(id){
            axios.get('/dashboard/getCountryName/'+id).then(res=>{
                console.log(res.data.success);
                this.country_name = res.data.success;
            });
        },
        getCountries(){
            axios.get('/dashboard/getCountries').then(res=>{
                this.countries = res.data;
            })
        },

     },

    mounted() {
        this.getCities();
        this.getCountries();
    }
}
```

the two functions getcities and get country name in the citiescontroller

```
public function getCities(){
    $cities = City::orderBy('id','desc')->get();
    return response()->json($cities);
}
public function getCountryName($country_id){
    $country = DB::table('countries')->where('id','=',$country_id)->first();
    return response()->json(['success'=> $country->name],200);
}
```

Relationship code in Country Model

```
public function cities(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\City');
}
```

Relationship code in City Model

```
public function countries(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\City');
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact relationship between your cities and your counry tables ?

Comment: Please share the relationship code in both your City and Country models.

Comment: in country model

public function cities(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\City');
}


in city model
public function countries(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\City');
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating what should be pretty simple. If your [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships) are setup correctly, it is relatively trivial to include fields from the `Country` model in the serialization of the related `City` model.

Your relationships should look something like this:

**City.php**

```php
<?php

...

class City extends Model
{
  ...

  public function Country
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Country');
  }
}
```

**Country.php**

```php
<?php

...

class Country extends Model
{
  ...

  public function Cities
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\City');
  }
}
```

***NOTE:*** This setup requires a `country_id` column on the `cities` table

You currently have defined this relationship as a [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), which doesn't make much sense, considering the context. A `City` does not have many Countries. It ***belongsTo*** exactly ***one*** Country. The other side is fine, since a `Country` ***does*** have many Cities. Therefore, what you want here is a [one-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationship.

Once your model relationships are setup correctly, you can easily get the `Country` name for any `City`. I would do it like this:

**City.php**

```php
<?php

...

class City extends Model
{
  ...

  protected $with = ['country'];
}
```

This means that any time a `City` is loaded from the database, its related `Country` is [eager loaded](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Alternatively, you can eager load the related `Country` when you load all of the Cities:

**citiescontroller**

```php
public function getCities(){
    $cities = City::with('country')
                  ->orderBy('id','desc')
                  ->get();

    return response()->json($cities);
}
```

Regardless of which implementation you choose, your City component can access the `Country`'s fields through the `City` model:

```html
<tr v-if="cities.length > 0" v-for="(city,index) in cities" :id="city.id">

  ...

  <td>{{ city.country.name }}</td>

  ...

</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you its working fine now the problem was the relationship function in city model

Comment: @Vince Thank you, I have just learnt something new here is it relates to this piece of code `protected $with = ['country'];`. I didn't know something like that could be done.

Answer (score 0):

`Relationship code in City Model`

update this

```php
public function countries()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\City');
}
```

to

```php
public function country()
{
  // return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Country');
  return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
}
```

by the way you should rename `countries` to `country`